# How to add extra option to v-select after setting :items prop

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

I have a v-select, written like this :

```
                <v-select
                    ref="v_select_folder"
                    dense
                    hide-details
                    v-model="selectedPlanFolder"
                    label="PlanFolder"
                    :items="PlannedFolder"
                    item-text="node.name"
                    return-object
                    @change="setFolderNameAndID"
                >
```

The v-select gets the available options/values dropdown from `:items`, I would like to know how if there is a simple way I can add an extra aditional option , without touching the items prop. Something like :

```
                <v-select
                    ref="v_select_folder"
                    dense
                    hide-details
                    v-model="selectedPlanFolder"
                    label="PlanFolder"
                    :items="PlannedFolder"
                    item-text="node.name"
                    return-object
                    @change="setFolderNameAndID"
                > 
                  <option>This is another select value</option>

                </v-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new array in place with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and add an item to it. You may want to add additional properties to the added item depending on how you process your data.

```html
<v-select
  ref="v_select_folder"
  dense
  hide-details
  v-model="selectedPlanFolder"
  label="PlanFolder"
  :items="[...PlannedFolder, { node: { name: 'name' } }]"
  item-text="node.name"
  return-object
  @change="setFolderNameAndID"
>
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I had to add a button to the end of items. I did this with `append-item` slot.

```
<v-select
  ref="v_select_folder"
  dense
  hide-details
  v-model="selectedPlanFolder"
  label="PlanFolder"
  :items="PlannedFolder"
  item-text="node.name"
  return-object
  @change="setFolderNameAndID"
>
     <template v-slot:append-item>
                      HELLO! I AM SOMETHING MORE!
     </template>
</v-select>
```

Source: [v-select API — Vuetify](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-append-item)